Cannot find module 'solc' when compiling in Node
Getting back to updating my Ethereum projects, but I am getting an error when I run node compile.js of:
Error: Cannot find module 'solc'
This is my compile.js file:
const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Campaign.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, "utf8");
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJSONSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract + ".json"),
    output[contract]
  );
}

Is the above no longer a valid configuration of the compile.js file?
I guess I should be clear, I already tried npm install and npm install solc and I am still getting the above error.
I also noticed I was using fs.outputJSONSync instead of fs.outputJsonSync.

It's unknown what's the structure of the project. What matters is whether the package is really installed and can be resolved. You need to verify with your eyes that a) compile.js is in the same or nested dir of the current project (where package.json is contained) and b) node_modules/solc/package.json exists (relative to the location of package.json)

Please check that you have a configured package.json file in the same directory as compile.js. And make sure it has solc in its dependencies like this:
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node compile.js",
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "solc": "^X.X.X" // an appropriate version
    },
}

If not, install using:
npm install solc

Then try running node compile.js again.
